# What's the correct way to create a new Spring Roo Project with multiple maven modules?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How do I configure Spring STS to work with an existing multi-module Roo project or create a new one from scratch?

Let's take the first case: Creating the project outside of the STS with the Roo shell.

All I do is create the parent project and add a maven module to it.  I have not setup JPA or created any entities.

When importing this kind of project (as an existing Maven project), Spring STS doesn't attach a Java project nature.  As a result, I can't use the content-assist features of the IDE, or perform refactoring (STS complains the code isn't on the build path).

In the second case, I just want to create a new project from within the STS and start using Roo with multiple maven modules that will be created later.

When using the New Spring Roo Project wizard, I select the package type to be "POM" and let the wizard do it's job. However, errors are reported in the Problems view.  STS is complaining it can't find the expected source folders (e.g., src/main/java ...).

Why is this so damn hard?

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Well I've been using Roo for a while and noticed the same anomalies you just reported. I didn't check your blog yet, but marked for further reading.

Anyway, for my multi-module projects, I usually create them inside or outside STS. Both resulting in the same problems you reported (#1 wrong parent project structure, not finding src, and #2 corrupting projects after importing as Maven projects).

First thing I'd like to clarify is that you don't have to run "perform eclipse" before importing a project into STS, or any Eclipse version with the Maven Plugin. The import will work (with previous flaws) just by the "Import Maven Project" option (and this is also explicitly written in Roo manual).

As for the issues we are talking about, well, I usually remove Roo nature from child projects' POM, to avoid opening Roo Shell (if it happens, Roo tend to delete some .aj files and, as you said, it will corrupt your project). Then I stick to Roo only by using inside the parent project, and then using the "module focus" command to work with child projects.

I believe Spring team will make everything works fine in due time, but for now, Roo is a great option and I believe those workarounds are worthy to keep using it inside Eclipse/STS.

Best regards,
Thiago Uriel

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to work with your Roo console based project in Eclipse - you need to run `perform eclipse` in your Spring Roo shell. Internally, it calls the Maven Eclipse Plugin and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to make sure your Maven project can be imported successfully to Eclipse / STS.

Related to the multi module projects, please see existing questions related to multi module projects on StackOverflow.

Cheers.

Comment: I spent a few days this week playing with Roo and the STS, and found that certain events don't get communicated between the too.  This can lead to a messed up project, all because you expected the tool to do something.  I've documented what I found, with steps to reproduce, and my solutions here: http://www.brainwreckage.com/2012/03/project-synchronization-problems-with.html

Comment: Great. Most of the issues you have mentioned can be solved by simply enabling 'Refresh using native hooks or polling' option in your eclipse workspace preferences.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the results are the same with just two exceptions:

In the first test case, step 12, the STS did correctly create the src/main/resources folder.
In the third test case, step 12, when opening the pom.xml file, the STS did not complain of a NullPointerException.

Other than those two differences, all the problems I describe are still encountered.  Try these for yourself.  If you have different results, I'd very much like to know.

-Jeff